# Novice parse error T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Tags: cakephp, php, parse-error

I'm starting to make my first steps into CakePHP 1.3, and I'm having a parse error I can't find. I'm trying the [main tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1536/Creating-Post-Views) and encountering this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW, expecting ')' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite.com/app/views/posts/index.ctp on line 11

the file affected is:

```
<h1>Posts</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Creation date</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $post['Post']['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'], array ('controller', => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $post['Post']['created']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line

```
 <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'], array ('controller', => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])); ?></td>
```

you need to remove the , after controller.

And I think you need to add an ) after ´view´

Comment: yep! it was visible indeed... thank you!